# "Could NOT find KDE4Workspace (missing: KDE4Workspace_CONFIG) (Required is at least version "4.9.80")"

Tags: kde, compiling

I have been trying to install oxygen-transparent on my kubuntu 14.04 installation for a while now, and every time it fails with the following error:

```
Aspire-7560:~/oxygen-transparent/oxygen-transparent$ sudo make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
sawyer@sawyer-Aspire-7560:~/oxygen-transparent/oxygen-transparent$ sudo apt-get install oxygen-transparent
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oxygen-transparent
sawyer@sawyer-Aspire-7560:~/oxygen-transparent$ chmod +x oxygen-setup.pl
sawyer@sawyer-Aspire-7560:~/oxygen-transparent$ ./oxygen-setup.pl
--- oxygen transparent easy setup script

--- checking out source code
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/oxygen-transparent
Cloning into 'oxygen-transparent'...
remote: Counting objects: 2844, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (793/793), done.
remote: Total 2844 (delta 2367), reused 2489 (delta 2049)
Receiving objects: 100% (2844/2844), 2.79 MiB | 545.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2367/2367), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
mv oxygen-transparent src
cd /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent

--- running cmake
mkdir -p /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build
cd /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix` -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/src
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.6 (using /usr/bin/qmake)
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for _POSIX_TIMERS
-- Looking for _POSIX_TIMERS - found
-- Found Automoc4: /usr/bin/automoc4  
-- Found Perl: /usr/bin/perl (found version "5.18.2") 
-- Found Phonon: /usr/include (Required is at least version "4.3.80") 
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_FPIE_SUPPORT
-- Performing Test HAVE_FPIE_SUPPORT - Success
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_W_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_W_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL - Success
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_GCC_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_GCC_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Found KDE 4.12 include dir: /usr/include
-- Found KDE 4.12 library dir: /usr/lib
-- Found the KDE4 kconfig_compiler preprocessor: /usr/bin/kconfig_compiler
-- Found automoc4: /usr/bin/automoc4
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find KDE4Workspace (missing: KDE4Workspace_CONFIG) (Required is
  at least version "4.9.80")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/FindKDE4Workspace.cmake:70 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
system cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix` -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/src>&1 failed: 256
sawyer@sawyer-Aspire-7560:~/oxygen-transparent$ cd build
sawyer@sawyer-Aspire-7560:~/oxygen-transparent/build$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for sawyer: 
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
sawyer@sawyer-Aspire-7560:~/oxygen-transparent/build$ 

the output found in the error log file is this:

Determining if the Q_WS_WIN exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec242714903/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec242714903.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec242714903.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec242714903.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -I/usr/include/qt4    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec242714903.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: error: ‘Q_WS_WIN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   return ((int*)(&Q_WS_WIN))[argc];
                   ^
/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec242714903.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec242714903/fast] Error 2

File /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef Q_WS_WIN
  return ((int*)(&Q_WS_WIN))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the Q_WS_QWS exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec283792793/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec283792793.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec283792793.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec283792793.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -I/usr/include/qt4    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec283792793.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: error: ‘Q_WS_QWS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   return ((int*)(&Q_WS_QWS))[argc];
                   ^
/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec283792793.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec283792793/fast] Error 2

File /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef Q_WS_QWS
  return ((int*)(&Q_WS_QWS))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the Q_WS_MAC exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3368427543/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3368427543.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3368427543.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3368427543.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -I/usr/include/qt4    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3368427543.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: error: ‘Q_WS_MAC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   return ((int*)(&Q_WS_MAC))[argc];
                   ^
/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3368427543.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3368427543/fast] Error 2

File /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef Q_WS_MAC
  return ((int*)(&Q_WS_MAC))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec1033947317/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1033947317.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1033947317.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1033947317.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1033947317.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec1033947317
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1033947317.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1033947317.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec1033947317 -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1033947317.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec1033947317] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec1033947317/fast] Error 2

File /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec368632354/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec368632354.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec368632354.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec368632354.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec368632354.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec368632354
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec368632354.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec368632354.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec368632354 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sawyer/oxygen-transparent/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec368632354] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec368632354/fast] Error 2
```

I really want oxygen on my system, but I have absolutely no idea where to start on this. What went wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Ytry with installing `kde-style-oxygen` package without compilings.

Comment: when I run "sudo apt-get install kde-style-oxygen-transparent" it says it's in its latest version, even though it does NOT show up in the themes menu

Comment: try with purge and reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**oxygen-transparent**

The oxygen-transparent has a KDE-LOOK page: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/oxygen-transparent?content=127752

It is telling:

> - Depending on the distribution you have the name of the packages might change a bit
> - there are usually more packages needed by the packages above and installed via dependency.
>
>   For instance,
>
> sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake kdelibs5-dev
>   kdebase-workspace-dev libxrender-dev libx11-dev git
>
> should work on recent enough Ubuntu...

Installing those and downloading the sources:

```
$ git clone git://anongit.kde.org/oxygen-transparent
Cloning into 'oxygen-transparent'...
remote: Counting objects: 2844, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (793/793), done.
remote: Total 2844 (delta 2371), reused 2485 (delta 2049)
Receiving objects: 100% (2844/2844), 2.79 MiB | 134.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2371/2371), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Making a build directory to the oxygen-tansparent three:

```
$ mkdir -p builddir
```

Changing the work directory to the 'builddir' and running the cmake:

```
$ cd builddir && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix`
```

Output should tell if the cmake run was ok:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
...
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: .../oxygen-tansparent/builddir
```

In the 'builddir':

```
../builddir$ make
```

If everything OK:

```
Scanning dependencies of target oxygentransparentstyle_automoc
Generating oxygenanimation.moc
[  0%] Built target oxygentransparentstyle_automoc
[  1%] Generating oxygeninactiveshadowconfiguration.h, oxygeninactiveshadowconfiguration.cpp
[  1%] Generating oxygenactiveshadowconfiguration.h, oxygenactiveshadowconfiguration.cpp
...
[100%] Building CXX object style/config/CMakeFiles/oxygen-transparent-settings.dir/main.o
Linking CXX executable oxygen-transparent-settings
[100%] Built target oxygen-transparent-settings
```

After this the installation step:

```
sudo make install
```

**Alternative - Searching from the PPA**

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=kde-style-oxygen-transparent

or/and

https://www.google.ca/search?q=kde-style-oxygen-transparent+.deb+site:https://launchpad.net/

Downloading i386/amd64 package

[image]

Installing...

[image]

Enabling the oxygen-transparent from the KDE system settings...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `kdebase-workspace-dev` package and see if that makes it work for you. I think you are just missing some packages (usually ending in `-dev`) that it needs to have around when it is compiling. I just usually search the error on google, like `Could NOT find KDE4Workspace (missing: KDE4Workspace_CONFIG)` and usually you will find something telling you what package you need.